# Delete rows with symbol '?' at the end using sql query

Tags: sql, mariadb

I want to delete rows with join two tables that contains phone number which end with symbol '?'. The rows are shown just like the picture below:

This is my query. But it shows syntax error
**#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS A JOIN `maid_3` AS B ON A.id_user = B.id_user WHERE notel LIKE '%?'' at line 1**

```
DELETE FROM `maid_2` AS A 
JOIN `maid_3` AS B 
    ON A.id_user = B.id_user 
WHERE notel LIKE '%?'
```

[image]

What's wrong with my query?

Comment: Does it say anything more than just "Syntax error"? What is the full error message? Could it be that you can't use alias' on tables you delete from?

Comment: I edited my question. You can see the error. And I tried remove the alias but it appear the same error @LasseV.Karlsen

Comment: Try prepending the parameter variable with % then change the query to use `LIKE ?`

Comment: sorry, but what do you mean? I tried change to LIKE '?' but also show the same error @CodeUK

Comment: I assume you're using PHP and moreso this is a prepared statement? If so, then say your search term is stored in variable $searchTerm... use $searchTerm = "%$searchTerm". In the SQL query, dont wrap the ? with any quotes. It should just be `LIKE ?`. Not `LIKE '?'`

Comment: which RDBMS it is ? Postgresql ?

Comment: It is MariaDB, from the error message. It's an offshoot from MySQL.

Comment: If you replace `DELETE` with `SELECT *`, does the statement then work and give you the data you want to delete?

Comment: yess, it is. it display what I want when I change to SELECT * @LasseV. Karlsen

Comment: I'm not using prepared statement. I use LIKE '%?' because at the end of my phone number data shows symbol ? like the picture above. @CodeUK

Comment: @nerdgirl Is my solution working for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
DELETE A 
FROM `maid_2` AS A 
JOIN `maid_3` AS B 
ON A.id_user = B.id_user 
WHERE notel LIKE '%?'
```

You are trying to delete data when there are multiple tables present in the delete query and in MariaDB there is Delete Syntax for Multiple-Table in which you have to mention the table from which rows need to be deleted:

```
DELETE [LOW_PRIORITY] [QUICK] [IGNORE]
tbl_name[.*] [, tbl_name[.*]] ...
FROM table_references
[WHERE where_condition]
```

For more info you can go through below link:

```
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/delete/
```